# "Apply for" vs. "apply to"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Here I want to say that this function just should be applied to the following classes: A, B and C.

> This function just applies for/to A, B and C.

But once again I am not sure which preposition should I use ?

Comment: apply v.intr. 1. To be pertinent or relevant:a rule that *applies to* everyone. link http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=apply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context,

> [**Apply:**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/apply) to be pertinent or relevant; have a bearing on; concern
>
> - A rule that applies to everyone.
> - What I have said does not apply to you.

So, the correct answer is:

> This function just applies **to** Conductors, RYSP and Officers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but can you elabore a little more ?

Comment: @utxeee I have edited my answer a bit. I hope, now, you will understand it better with the meaning **concern**.

Answer (score 22):

"Apply to" is used when we are saying where something is relevant. e.g. "That rule doesn't apply to me." "Normal logic does not apply to political debates."

"Apply for" is used when we are requesting something. e.g. "I would like to apply for the job of senior sanitation engineer." "Jack applied for a credit card."

Comment: @feynman Fluent English speakers do not say, "I applied to a job". They say, "I applied for a job."

Comment: No, that's right. Sorry if this is confusing. You "apply to" a program or organization, but you "apply for" a position. So, "I applied to the graduate program", but "I applied for a graduate assistant job". Or, "I applied to Fwacbar University", but "I applied for a slot at Fwacbar University".

Answer (score 3):

Apply to:
This rule applies to everyone.
Apply yourself to this task.

Apply for:
To apply for a job