# "Apply for" vs. "apply to", a different case

Tags: prepositions

> The method A is applied for the determination of B.

or

> The method A is applied to the determination of B.

I often see these phrases in scientific texts. But which one is correct?

There is another post here asking a seemingly [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72490/apply-for-vs-apply-to), however, the context is quite different. I am sure, many scientific writers hesitate for at least a second about the choice of preposition in this situation.

Comment: Both work. Both make sense. Both ultimately mean the same though through different semantic routes. I do not hesitate -- it depends on the broader context because of the subtle difference in meaning.

Comment: @Kris Thank you, very interesting remark! What do you mean by "different semantic routes" ? Can you, please, elaborate, I would be eager to learn.